# Rails 3.1: testing "DELETE 'destroy'" in controller and route specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm testing an app that uses Sorcery for authentication. I have a sessions controller which handles user signin / signout with tests to go along with the actions. I understand that a destroy action usually takes an id as a parameter, but it's unnecessary with a signout feature.

### routes.rb

```
resources :sessions

# match "/signout", :to => "sessions#destroy"
```

### sessions_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
  it "should log the user out" do
    login_user(Factory(:user))
    delete :destroy
    controller.current_user.should be_nil
    controller.should_not be_signed_in
  end 
end
```

### session_routes_spec.rb

```
it "should route DELETE /sessions to sessions#destroy" do
  { :delete => "/sessions" }.should route_to(
    :controller => "sessions",
    :action => "destroy"
  )
end
```

Both of the above tests fail because the route expects an id. Is there a way to get rid of this necessity? I know I could just use the named "signout_path" route, but I am just curious if I can still use session_path, :method => :delete without passing it an id.

What's really shocking to me is if I uncomment the match "/signout" the controller spec passes (however, the route spec does not). How does the match line cause the controller spec to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the destroy action as :collection method of sessions resources, in your config/routes.rb:

```
resources :sessions, :collection => [:destroy]
```

By default destroy is an "member" method that requires a resource specified to work on it.